# Java file object size returning 0

Tags: java, file

```
System.out.print("1");
System.out.println(ts.getComponent());
System.out.println(ts.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor));
String dir = ts.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor).toString();

File file = new File(dir);
System.out.println(file.getName());
System.out.println(file.getPath());
System.out.println(file.getTotalSpace());

long num = file.length();
System.out.println(num);
```

**Output**

```
1javax.swing.JTable[,0,0,556x64,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@1baabbd6,flags=251658568,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,autoCreateColumnsFromModel=true,autoResizeMode=AUTO_RESIZE_SUBSEQUENT_COLUMNS,cellSelectionEnabled=false,editingColumn=-1,editingRow=-1,gridColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=35,g=35,b=36],preferredViewportSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=450,height=400],rowHeight=16,rowMargin=0,rowSelectionAllowed=true,selectionBackground=DerivedColor(color=57,105,138 parent=nimbusSelectionBackground offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=57,105,138,selectionForeground=DerivedColor(color=255,255,255 parent=nimbusLightBackground offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=255,255,255,showHorizontalLines=false,showVerticalLines=false]
[C:\Users\Ye\Desktop\Spotify.lnk]
Spotify.lnk]
[C:\Users\Ye\Desktop\Spotify.lnk]
0
```

I dont get how file size  is 0 despite testing it with few files

Comment: Have you tried checking different file _types_? i.e., not Windows shortcuts.

Comment: yea i tried with some other exe and files

Answer (score 3):

Chances are that you're *either checking the length of a directory* OR that the *specified `File` doesn't exist.*

From the documentation of the [`File.length`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#length()), it returns:

> The length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname, or `0L` if the file does not exist.  Some operating systems may return `0L` for pathnames denoting system-dependent entities such as devices or pipes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with the path String you are providing to the `File` constructor. The value `[C:\Users\Ye\Desktop\Spotify.lnk]` is not a valid pathname for the `File` constructor for the file your are trying to access. This is visible in your print statement's output for `file.getName()` which is `Spotify.lnk]` and not `Spotify.lnk`. The file object you are trying to get the size of is a new file with the name Spotify.lnk**]** that **has** the size 0.

I don't know whether you have any other way to get the file name other than `getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor).toString()` but you can try to sanitise the file name using the following code :

```
    String dirTemp = ts.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor).toString();
    dir = dirTemp.substring(1, dirTemp.length() - 1);
    // Then create the file using this dir String.
    File file = new File(dir);
```

This would work for the current output of `getTransferData()#toString()` that you are getting, but might not work if, say, someone changes the `toString()` implementation.

**Edit :**

As correctly pointed by @MichaelA.Schaffrath, the object returned by `ts.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)` is actually a `List<File>`. So, there isn't even a need to construct a new `File` object again. Just cast the returned value as a `List` and use the first value for the `File` object.

Comment: No need for string parsing. He is using DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor, which means getTransferData will return a java.util.List. He just needs to cast his result from getTransferData to List and get the first element.

Comment: @MichaelA.Schaffrath , Thanks I wasn't aware of that... Will update my answer with the same.